# Gradle "package org.jfree.chart does not exist" in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jfreechart

I'm using IntelliJ to build a Spring Boot Java project with Gradle. I have `jcommon-1.0.23.jar` and `jfreechart-1.0.19.jar` in a libs directory and follow [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project) to add Jar files as libraries in IntelliJ.

It works fine in another project, but in this project, nothing works and I got the error

> Task :compileJava D:\dev\logsview\logsview\src\main\java\com\tool\logsview\generic\entity\GanttChart.java:4: error: package org.jfree.chart does not exist import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;

The weird thing is after some tries, the IDEA doesn't show errors, but still fails when compiled.

Java file:
[image]

Lib dir structure:
[image]

Lib added in Project Structures Module:
[image]

Lib added in Project Structures Lib:
[image]

I have tried restarting the IDEA, recompiling, compiling using the command line and IDEA, etc.

Comment: For reference, version 1.5.3 is current.

Comment: Did you add dependency to your build.gradle?

Comment: Since you're using Gradle as a build system Project Structure settings might be lost after the project reload. Instead of manually adding dependencies to your project you can add https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jcommon/1.0.23 and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart/1.0.19 to your build.gradle file and reload the project.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov It works. Thanks for the info! For some reason, I thought build.gradle is used to add springboot-related dependencies only and other libraries should be added via Project Structure.